# Splitting a string with delimiter

Tags: string, d, dmd

OK, So I'm having a `string` and want to split it and return its parts in a string array.

This is my code :

```
// import std.algorithm;

string   include  = "one,two,three";
string[] paths    = splitter(include,",");
```

This throws an error : `Error: cannot cast from Result to string[]`

Even if I try adding a `cast(string[])` in front of the function call.

Any ideas?

Comment: @pmg My bad! Mistagged. It's D. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`splitter` returns a range which splits lazily.

To split eagerly, use `split` from `std.array`.

Alternatively, you can save the range to an array by using `std.array.array`, like this:

```
string[] paths = include.splitter(",").array();
```

Comment: Well, it worked like a charm. It seems that.. as much as I **love** D, there's too much that I'm still missing. Time to study! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Using split() from std.array might be more conventional in this case since it already deals with arrays and you wouldn't need to convert the type or anything, compared to splitter.

Requires:

```
import std.array;
```

Usage:

```
auto paths = split(include, ",");
```